# How do I use admore form in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do i repeat a form using a addmore button.It should be a dynamic form.

I used

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<input type='text' name='name'>";
}
</script>
```

But every time i click the button it overwrite on the previous.But I want to keep the previous input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml=document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml+"<input type='text' name='name'>\r\n";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing your old html because you used operator `=`. You need to concat with older html using `+=`.

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<input type='text' name='name'/>";
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
<div id="demo"></div>
```